# Zend_Navigation and Zend_Translation France accent

Tags: xml, zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-translate

I have setup a internet application with multi languages.

The navigation is set by navigation.xml, zend translation files are .php files.
Everything is going well but I cant make it to use accents for the france language
in my navigation.

When I put as an example 'è' in the navigation xml label directly it works like it
suppose to be but when I add this in the fr.php (translation array) and put it from
here in my xml file it does nothing.

What do I have to do to make this work?

Thanks 
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be fixed, I create a custom route for the navigation section.